# My Button only works when I click on a specific place Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hello my Problem is that if I click on the right or the left of my Button, it works well. But if I click on the middle, it doesn't even do the animation of click.

[image]

I can only click what I encircled in black, and I can't click what is encircled in red. It's the same for the menu Button, I can only click on the same spots. I already tried to delete the texts and to recreate the Buttons from scratch.
Also, as you can see on the picture below, the green outline of the collider is around the Button.

[image]

Comment: sounds like you have something else overlapping it

Comment: check the scene window the green outline shows the clickable button outline that takes input.

Comment: @Uzair yes I checked, the green outline is around my Button, i edited my post to show you

Answer (score 0):

So the Problem was that a textmeshpro component had a collider overlapping my buttons, and it was invisible. Thanks to @BugFinder, I finally found a solution. Hope it Will help others